# Deploy an Application on Server using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, devops, system-administration

I'm new to Jenkins, i've build the dotnet application in jenkins using microsft publish command now i want to move the exe of the application from local system (where jenkins is installed) to a actual server. how to do it? how can i move code from my local system to server. Can anyone please guide me.
One way is to zip the exe and manually deploy it on server i want to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to:

- Deploy your application to an Azure Virtual machine
- And also automate the process

For `#1`: I would highly recommend using [Visual Studio to publish your app to the Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio) from your local machine for ad-hoc deployments, unless you have a hard dependency on using Jenkins.

For `#2`: There are a few ways in which you can do this. Here are some great resources to refer:

- [Deploy to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops)
- [Migrate an ASP.NET Web application to an Azure Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/migration/vm)
- [Deploy your ASP.NET app to Azure virtual machines by using Azure DevOps Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-vms)

[Here](https://dev.to/lasanga/setting-up-ci-cd-pipeline-to-deploy-a-net-core-application-to-an-iis-server-through-azure-devops-53o1) is another detailed blog that walks one through the CI/CD setup using Azure DevOps.